# perl won't locate down_force method of Thread::Semaphore?

Tags: multithreading, perl, semaphore

I verified that the package is installed with perldoc -l Thread::Semaphore, but i still get this error:
`Can't locate object method "down_force" via package "Thread::Semaphore" at <filename line#>`

my code:

```
: #use perl
   eval 'exec perl -S $0 ${1+"$@"}'
   if 0;

use threads;
use threads::shared;
use Thread::Semaphore;

my $s = Thread::Semaphore->new();

$s->down_force();    #it complains about this one

#some code here...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have [version 2.09 of Thread::Semaphore](http://search.cpan.org/~jdhedden/Thread-Semaphore-2.09/lib/Thread/Semaphore.pm), which doesn't have the `down_force()` method. Try upgrading to the [most recent version](http://search.cpan.org/~jdhedden/Thread-Semaphore/), which is currently 2.12.

Comment: If you are using cpan, you can do it with:> sudo cpan > upgrade Thread::Semaphore